# Access VAR_STAT CONSTANTS of an FB externally without instantiation in CODESYS V3

Tags: codesys

I would like to have the behaviour of a public constant in C#. So:

**In CODESYS V3, is it possible to externally access VAR_STAT CONSTANTS of an FB without instantiation in CODESYS V3? and If not, what would be the most proper way to do so?**

The emphasis here is "on the FB", and with externally, I mean other places in the program.
There are a couple of work-arounds given below, but maybe more cleaner solutions are at hand.

An application of this would be having a list of text resources that I would like to have available at other places in the code. e.g. a list of pneumatic cylinder states:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK PUBLIC CylinderStates
VAR_STAT CONSTANT
    Idle : STRING := 'Idle';
    MoveToWork : STRING := 'Move to Work';
    MoveToBase : STRING := 'Move to Base';
    AtWork : STRING := 'At Base';
    AtBase : STRING := 'At Base';
    Error : STRING := 'Error';
END_VAR
```

So that in PRG_MAIN, I could do something like this (this does not work):

```
str := CylinderStates.MoveToWork;
```

This generates the error:

- Function block 'CylinderStates' must be instantiated to be accessed.

Other examples are constants like PI, that I would like to contain under a Math FB (similar to how it is done in C#)

I have a couple of workarounds for this

### Work-around 1: Instantiating in GVL or VARs

It is possible to define an instance in a global variable list and then call it from there (this works):

```
str := GVL.CylinderStatesInst.MoveToWork;
```

Another option is to create an instance in the VAR list of the current FB/PRG/...

### Work-around 2: TO_STRING attribute

Defining an enum and adding the attribute 'to_string':

```
{attribute 'to_string'}
TYPE CylinderState :
(
    Idle,
    MoveToWork,
    MoveToBase ,
    AtWork,
    AtBase,
    Error
);
END_TYPE
```

Allows me to do the following:

```
str := TO_STRING(CylinderState.AtBase);
```

The greatest downside of this is that I cannot use spaces or special characters.

### Work-around 3: flatten into GVL

This is something I do not want to do, but also provides a solution:

```
VAR_GLOBAL
    CylinderStates_Idle : STRING := 'Idle';
    CylinderStates_MoveToWork : STRING := 'Move to Work';
    CylinderStates_MoveToBase : STRING := 'Move to Base';
    CylinderStates_AtWork : STRING := 'At Base';
    CylinderStates_AtBase : STRING := 'At Base';
    CylinderStates_Error : STRING := 'Error';
END_VAR
```

### Work-around 4: Dedicated GVL:

Simply creating a dedicated GVL also does the trick, **and seems like the best option**, but the question is if it is possible to define the constants **on the FB**.

```
{attribute 'qualified_only'}
VAR_GLOBAL
    Idle : STRING := 'Idle';
    MoveToWork : STRING := 'Move to Work';
    MoveToBase : STRING := 'Move to Base';
    AtWork : STRING := 'At Base';
    AtBase : STRING := 'At Base';
    Error : STRING := 'Error';
END_VAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guiorgy's answer is correct, but a part is missing:

> In CODESYS V3, is it possible to externally access VAR_STAT CONSTANTS
> of an FB without instantiation in CODESYS V3?

As Guiorgy explained, it's not possible.

> and If not, what would be the most proper way to do so?

This can be a little relative depending on your application and resources, specifically in your examples it seems that you want to "Categorize" status using `STRINGS`, usually I do this using `Enumerator` (Work-around 2), and only converting to `STRINGS` if I need to display them in a HMI for the user, you could create a "Converter" using a simple function using a `CASE OF` with direct strings.

```
FUNCTION CylinderStateToString : STRING
VAR_INPUT
    State : CylinderState;
END_VAR
VAR
END_VAR

CASE State OF
    CylinderState.Idle :
        CylinderStateToString := 'Idle';
    CylinderState.MoveToWork :
        CylinderStateToString := 'Move To Work';
    CylinderState.MoveToBase :
        CylinderStateToString := 'Move To Base';
    CylinderState.AtWork :
        CylinderStateToString := 'At Work';
    CylinderState.AtBase :
        CylinderStateToString := 'At Base';
    CylinderState.Error :
        CylinderStateToString := 'Error';
    ELSE
        CylinderStateToString := 'NA';
END_CASE
```

And use like that:

```
MyTest := CylinderStateToString(State := CylinderState.MoveToBase);
```

Note that in this case I would put this "Converter" in a low priority task that would only pass the information in STRING to the HMI and in the rest of the program it would only use the enumerator.

---

If you need or want to use constants in STRINGS, what I recommend is to use `GVL` (Work-around 4), in Codesys 3.5 you can create several, so create one with the name `CylinderState` and declare the constants, then just use it normally:

[image]

Then you can use it like this:

```
PROGRAM PRG_Main
VAR
    MyTest : STRING;
END_VAR

MyTest := CylinderState.Idle;
```

[image]

Here, in the "Input Assistant" you can see how the structure looks like, where we can still use another GVL...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the codesys [documentation](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_vartypes_var_stat/) on `VAR_STAT`:

> You can access static variables only from within the namespace where the variables are declared (like static variables in C).

I assume this means you can't access them from outside.

However, from your use case, I don't see why you are trying to use a `VAR_STAT`. From what I understand, they are used to declare variables inside a function that should be retained between calls, for example a counter. A function block is basically equivalent to a C# class, so all the variables declared inside it are retained withing the same instance (unless you use `VAR_TEMP`).

Especially, you are want constant variables, which can just be declared inside a `VAR CONSTANT` block inside the function block:

```pascal
FUNCTION_BLOCK POU
VAR CONSTANT
    K: REAL := 0.5;
    B: REAL := 5;
END_VAR
VAR_INPUT
    in: REAL;
END_VAR
VAR_INPUT
    out: REAL;
END_VAR
VAR
END_VAR
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK

out := K * in + B;
```

```pascal
p: POU;
k: REAL := p.K;
```

Comment: I used the `VAR_STAT` since this as the same as a static in C#: a variable scope that is shared for all instances. The idea is that the variables declared in VAR_STAT only take up memory once; even if the POU is instantiated multiple times. It could be that VAR CONSTANT has the same result, but I am not sure of this.

Your answer is correct, but still requires instantiation of the POU.

Comment: [The constants are replaced with the initial value when the code is compiled](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_struct_reference_operands/), so they take no additional variables, however, if the literal is big (like long strings) and used in many places, it could bloat the source code I guess. Though, you are right about requiring an instance of the object to access the constants, however, personally I haven't run into a case where I needed to use that constant without using the object itself. Hope you find something that works for you!